# ¿Cómo puedo validar un dni en Java sin RegeXP?

Tags: java

Necesito validar el dni en java sin regeXP.
Que tenga ocho números y una letra, teniendo en total una longitud de 9.
He intentado hacer un rango para el abecedario, pero no sé como hacerlo.
Para los números he hecho un simple if para comprobar esto e funciona.

Comment: Y como es el formato?

Comment: si la longitud es 9, si puedes convertir a número entero los primeros 8 caracteres, y si el último caracter no puede ser convertido a número.... creo que haría lo que quieres, pero no aseguro nada porque tu pregunta no está bien explicada ni muestras código

Comment: Coloca el código que has intentado aunque no funcione y el formato a validar (las letras permitidas en qué posiciones etc). Ten en cuenta que stack overflow en español es un sitio común para todos los países de habla hispana, y la mayoría tiene su propio formato de dni, por lo que es necesario que lo aclares. Presiona [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/537392/edit) y agrega detalles a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con esto..

```
    private boolean esNumero(cadena:String){
    char caracter;
    boolean bandera=true;
    for(int i= 0 ; i < cadena.lentgh && bandera ; i++){
     caracter= cadena.charAt(i);
     if(caracter<48||caracter>57){
      bandera=false;
     }
    }
    return bandera;
    }
```

puedes usar el codigo ascii para verificar caracteres, ya que los strings no pueden diferenciar de numeros.entonces el rango de 0 a 9 en ascii es del valor 48 al 57 cualquier otra representacion ascii diferente te devolvera falso , puedes largar una excepcion tambien. pero eso ya lo decides tu

perdon, si no se comprendio muy bien, soy nuevo aqui.

Comment: Saludos @GalioRules, gracias por tu aporte, pero antes de responder a una publicación asegúrate siempre de que se ajuste a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no necesariamente todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas ya que muchas "como ésta" carecen de información como para responderla de forma correcta y lo mas seguro es que terminen cerradas, también te invito a leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). ;)